# Why does my Visual Studio 2010 default to a horizontal windows split if I quit then reopen it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional at work and up until a couple of weeks ago I have had no problems. But now whenever I open an instance of VS 2010 it defaults to horizontal split. I *never* split my windows horizontally, so this is very annoying. It happens consistently, every time on every project.

Here is how VS2010 looked before I closed the window:
[image]

I close it and reopen in that project, and:
[image]

Arg! The only plugin I use is ReSharper, in case it's relevant.

Comment: this is happening to me too but I don't have resharper installed.  Very annoying since there's no way to switch it back without dragging all the windows off and then back on.

Answer (score 2):

I too had exactly this problem running VS2010 with no addins.
It appears that everyone else submitting comments and solutions really hasn't understood the problem.

Here is my solution...
The problem manifests itself when you close down Visual Studio with the windows in vertical tab groups. Then when you re open the solution FROM THE SOLUTION FILE, the tab groups are now grouped horizontally. (So no, nothing is "saved")

The problem does NOT occur if you open Visual Studio, then open the project from within Visual Studio!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a feature called **Tab Grouping** and it can be enabled horizontally or vertically. As far as I can tell, it's the same thing as a window *split* to enable you to see 2 or more sections of the same file simultaneously. The difference is that `Tab Grouping` is saved between sessions i.e. if you close and re-open Visual Studio, **this setting will be retained**!

To disable it:

[image]

In your particular case, you have 3 files opened in each group. This means you will have to repeat the procedure 3 times either starting on the left or right side and moving each file either to the left or right side until you only have one group open.

In case somebody wants to enable it (or the horizontal version):

[image]

**UPDATE**:
Googling around I was able to find numerous people complaining about all sorts of bugs with splitting/grouping code windows while using ReSharper. You could try removing ReSharper, ensure windows are *not* split/grouped, restart VS to verify if it worked, then re-install ReSharper?

Comment: You don't explain why this happens every time he opens VS.

Comment: It is saved between sessions. Updated my answer.

Comment: What do you mean it's saved? This makes no sense at all, I never set any kind of grouping, WHAT is saved? I have never in my life even touched a "grouping" setting. My question is why does VS CHANGE from vertical to horizontal splitting?

Comment: You pasted screenshots. I have VS2010. I can recreate your screenshots by enabling grouping. Therefore you have somehow enabled grouping. What do you mean what do I mean it's saved? Are you a programmer? **Saved** means that the _grouping of files_ is remembered between Visual Studio sessions i.e. if you enable the grouping feature, shutdown VS, and start it again, grouping of files will be restored. Have you tried doing what I suggested to disable it? If you're only interested in knowing _why_ it changes, I suggest updating your question because I didn't see that question.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100726/how-to-change-horizontal-tab-group-to-vertical-tab-group

Basically, **edit your VS settings file** and remove the Orientation="Vertical" that is there.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple.

Just go to `Tools -> Option -> HTML Designer -> General` tab, check the option `Split views vertically`.

This will by default splits the window vertically always.

Note: This does not work for `.master` file.